# How to create hierarchical taxonomy programmatically drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I want to create hierarchical taxonomy using my custom module.
I get all the vocabulary list using taxonomy_get_vocabularies().

My issue is when i select any vocabulary or parent related child should be list in another select list / dropdown.

My code :-

```
enter code here

<?php
function student_addform($form, &$form_state) {

  $vocabulary = taxonomy_get_vocabularies();
  $checklist_vocab_array = array();
  foreach ($vocabulary as $item) {
    $vocab_vid = $item->vid;
    $vocab_name = $item->name;
    $checklist_vocab_array[$vocab_vid] = $vocab_name;
  }

  $form['vocabulary_list'] = array(
    '#type'             => 'select',
    '#title'            => t('List of current Classes.'),
    '#position'         => 'left' ,
    '#options'          => $checklist_vocab_array ,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description'      => t('List of classes displayed as dropdown'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => '_student_records_callback_fields',
      'wrapper' => 'check-box-replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
      'event' => 'change' ,
    ),
  );

  $form['child-list'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Select fields of'),
    'options' => $term_list,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="check-box-replace">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  return $form;
}

function _student_records_callback_fields($form, $form_state) {
  $term_list = array();
  $vocabulary_id = $form['vocabulary_list']['#value'];
  $terms = taxonomy_get_tree($vocabulary_id); // Use the correct vocabulary id.
  $count = count($terms);
  for ($term = 0 ; $term < $count ; $term++) {
    $term_list[$terms[$term]->vid] = $terms[$term]->name;
  }

  return $term_list;
}
?>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should always create form elements in the form function, not in the callback.
When the callback is fired, the form function is called again allowing you to alter it. The callback usually only returns the form element.
So...

```
enter code here

<?php
function student_addform($form, &$form_state) {

  $vocabulary = taxonomy_get_vocabularies();
  $checklist_vocab_array = array();
  foreach ($vocabulary as $item) {
    $vocab_vid = $item->vid;
    $vocab_name = $item->name;
    $checklist_vocab_array[$vocab_vid] = $vocab_name;
  }

  $form['vocabulary_list'] = array(
    '#type'             => 'select',
    '#title'            => t('List of current Classes.'),
    '#position'         => 'left' ,
    '#options'          => $checklist_vocab_array ,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#description'      => t('List of classes displayed as dropdown'),
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => '_student_records_callback_fields',
      'wrapper' => 'check-box-replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',
      'event' => 'change' ,
    ),
  );

  // Check if a vocabulary is selected, if it is get the children and populate the second  dropdown.

  //something like this.

  // $term_list = array();
  // if(vocabulary is selected){
  //   $term_list = term children
  // }

  // you should be able to check if a vocabulary is selected by checking the
  // $form_state['values'] or $form_state['input'] (I forget which)

  $form['child-list'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Select fields of'),
    'options' => $term_list,
    '#prefix' => '<div id="check-box-replace">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
  );

  return $form;
}

function _student_records_callback_fields($form, $form_state) {
  return $form['child-list'];
}
```